# Windows 7 boots only with installation disk in the drive

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have 2 hard drives - one on SATA and one on standard ATA. On the SATA drive I have Windows 7. I decided to do a fresh install on the ATA drive. Everything is ok apart from the fact, that the new install is booting only when the installation DVD is in the drive. When it's not, it boots the old installation on SATA drive. Does anyone know why it can be?
My motherboard is Asus m2n-e.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the boot order in your bios?

Plus you might want to check your boot.ini file

If you have no idea what it says or is [try looking at it with EasyBCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyBCD). This program uses a GUI to show what your boot configuration is like. It might be that your disks are ordered the wrong way in your Master Boot Record.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
In bios it's set to boot first from CD, then from HDD. I can't specify order of the drives.

EasyBCD didn't show anything unusual - it show the currently loaded system as bootable and doesn't say anything about the other one.

Comment: What it might tell you is what partition it will boot from and possibly which drive is supposed to be the master drive

Answer (score 0):

I just responded to this question on another post. Please see:

[DISK BOOT FAILURE after upgrading power supply](https://superuser.com/questions/102018/disk-boot-failure-after-upgrading-power-supply/102039#102039)