# How to force a hard drive to shut down

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, shutdown

I have a hard drive in my computer that I'm not using.  I want Windows 7 to shut it down.  I don't want to have to manually remove the cable.

(The reason is that for some strange reason my computer will not boot if it's not connected. [disk boot failure after upgrading power supply](https://superuser.com/questions/102018/disk-boot-failure-after-upgrading-power-supply))

I know that Windows 7 will shut it down after a certain period of time of it not being used.  How can I force it to shut down without having to wait for this?

Comment: do you want to shut down the harddrive or just a partition?

Comment: I want to shut down the whole hard drive so that it is not powered on.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is connected to the computer, it will be powered on, you need to remove it physically and refresh the bios.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? For example Windows changes the power-state of harddrives to off after some time - depending to your settings - to save energy. I think you just have to search a little bit for how to change the powerstate of a device at msdn.com .
But also you could ask some software-developers for help (e.g. at http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can shut down a Hard Drive using **RevoSleep** https://www.meinfach.net/revosleep/. (If the download does not work, try downloading from chip.de/downloads/revoSleep_29717202.html)