# No SATA drives after PSU Upgrade

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, sata

I know this sounds a lot like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/102018/disk-boot-failure-after-upgrading-power-supply) but I just confirmed that my MBR is fine as well as the SSD drive in question.

What happened: I upgraded my be-quiet 700w PSU to the 1000w dark power pro. When I tried booting the system and none of the drives (all SATA) were detected, resulting in the "Boot device failure" error. After that I unplugged all but the boot drive, triple checked that all cables were in fact nice and tight inside their sockets, replaced both e-SATA and power cables ; still with the same outcome. Finally I reconnected my old PSU and sure enough the PC booted without any hassle (except of course for the [direful construction](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v2ykrw2ovbcwefj/2013-10-22%2021.50.49.jpg) that is currently occupying my desk).

Does anybody have any advice on how to proceed? Surely, it is possible the PSU is faulty but are there other explanations?

Thanks in advance

PS. if of any help: Motherboard is GIGABYTE GA-PH67A-UD3-B3 H67 LGA 1155

Comment: Have you tried putting the drives on a different power rail? The rail you might be using from the PSU could be faulty.

Comment: Yes I did that, no luck there, either.

Comment: What other devices if your PSU connected to? MB, HD, Video?, CDROM? When you go into the BIOS, does it show them?

Comment: I would suspect the drives aren't getting power for some reason.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I guess your right. I just tried connecting an HDD, it didn't even seem to spin up. @ Jason MB (24 pin, 2x P4), boot drive (SSD) and video.

Comment: If you can, inspect the modular sata cables and connectors and check them electrically. But I think that you are just wasting your time. If all modular cables connectors are properly plugged and you still don't have power on sata rails, than it's definitely PSU.

Comment: Agree with @NikolaD . My money is on a disconnected +12V line *inside* the PSU, from the switching block to the external power rails (but not to the mobo, which seems to be getting power). BTW, if the connection is *loose* (it could be on the board instead), there's a significant risk of a short circuit. I'd bring the PSU back to the shop and demand a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not I have had brand new power supply units that had an issue right out of the box.  The best method at this point for double checking the PSU is to get a hold of a PSU testing unit.  I have done several refurbs and repairs for buds & acquaintances as well as built or upgraded all of my own units for years.......... A decent little PSU tester is a must.

Your problem sounds a lot like there is simply no power or insufficient power being delivered to the SATA drives.  Also double check the actual SATA cables, be sure they are properly seated on the MB & the drive.  A PSU tester can be had for 10 -25 $$ but usually these days you have to order one, call on any friends or such you know who might have one available for you to borrow.  Good luck.

mark

Comment: Can't believe this took 6 month. I got my money back quite a while ago but it wasn't until today that I was notified, the PSU was actually faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting your BIOS by pulling the battery out and then check your BIOS for drive settings? It could be that the drives are on a wrong config after switching the PSU.

Comment: Not really likely... CMOS memory is protected by a checksum, so anything (voltage spike, etc.) that changed, i.e., *corrupted* the memory would have triggered an alert. Also, putting back the original PSU wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @Scout. I think it is a good thing to ask if the BIOS/UEFO settings are still correct, however 1) I do not think it is a full answer. It would be better as a comment. 2) Lserni is correct about the checksums.

Comment: @Iserni forgot about the checksum. You are right on that one.
Hennes, I am still trying to find out how to make a commment, can't find it yet ;) But will try to do my best.
But my question still stands about the BIOS settings