# My Windows 7 Professional needs to have the Windows 7 DVD in to boot from hard drive

Tags: windows-7, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 boots only with installation disk in the drive](https://superuser.com/questions/84779/windows-7-boots-only-with-installation-disk-in-the-drive)

This was a fresh install to begin with over 2 years ago.  Got a newer SSD and tried to clone to it but had a problem and had to back it out using minitool partition wizard I think.

Since then the system will not boot unless I have the Windows 7 DVD loaded.  All it does is go out and hit it and then it continues normally to boot from hard drive.  I checked the BCD and the boot manager is pointing to the correct drive.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?  If I ever lose my dvd drive (which I did, but had an usb external one for backup), I won't be able to boot. I don't want to wipe my install out and start again.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that the boot loader isn't configured properly. Though you said you checked BCD and it's pointing to the correct drive...

As a sanity check, try downloading [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (make sure it's the free version) and using that tool to ensure that the boot loader is set up properly? It's a GUI interface to bcdedit.exe and is very easy to use.